# Scheme recursive

Tags: scheme, racket

Deos anyone know, how I can make this funktion recursive by inserting the function somewhere? I am not allowed to use implemented functions for lists except append, make-pair(list) and reverse.

```
(: split-list ((list-of %a) -> (tuple-of (list-of %a) (list-of %a))))  
(check-expect (split-list (list 1 2)) (make-tuple (list 1) (list 2)))
(check-expect (split-list (list 1 2 3 4)) (make-tuple (list 1 3) (list 2 4)))
(check-expect (split-list (list 1 2 3)) (make-tuple (list 1 3) (list 2)))
(check-expect (split-list (list 1 2 3 4 5)) (make-tuple (list 1 3 5) (list 2 4)))
(check-expect (split-list (list 1 2 3 4 5 6)) (make-tuple (list 1 3 5) (list 2 4 6)))
(define split-list
  (lambda (x)
    (match x
      (empty empty)
      ((make-pair a empty) (make-tuple a empty))
      ((make-pair a (make-pair b empty)) (make-tuple (list a) (list b)))
      ((make-pair a (make-pair b c))  (make-tuple (list a (first c)) (list b (first(rest c))))))))
```

Code for make-tuple:

```
(define-record-procedures-parametric tuple tuple-of
  make-tuple
  tuple?
  (first-tuple
   rest-tuple))
```

Comment: What kind of language level? Where are the definitions of `make-pair` and `make-tuple`? How are they different?

Comment: Make-tuple is defined like this:(define-record-procedures-parametric tuple tuple-of
  make-tuple
  tuple?
  (first-tuple
   rest-tuple))

Comment: I am not allowed to use implemented functions for lists except append, make-pair and reverse.

Comment: Please post the code for `make-tuple` and `make-pair` in the question, and specify the language you're using.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: That doesn't seem to be standard Racket, it looks like your class is using some custom extension to the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can fix it using `match` and a [*named* `let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29), seen below as `loop`.

```
(define (split xs)
  (let loop ((xs xs)       ;; the list, initialized with our input
             (l empty)     ;; "left" accumulator, initialized with an empty list
             (r empty))    ;; "right" accumulator, initialized with an empty list
    (match xs
      ((list a b rest ...) ;; at least two elements
       (loop rest
             (cons a l)
             (cons b r)))
      ((cons a empty)      ;; one element
       (loop empty
             (cons a l)
             r))
      (else                ;; zero elements
       (list (reverse l)
             (reverse r))))))
```

Above we use a `loop` to build up *left* and *right* lists then we use `reverse` to return the final answer. We can avoid having to reverse the answer if we build the answer in reverse order! The technique used here is called [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

```
(define (split xs (then list))
  (match xs
    ((list a b rest ...)             ;; at least two elements
     (split rest
            (λ (l r)
              (then (cons a l)
                    (cons b r)))))
    ((cons a empty)                  ;; only one element
     (then (list a) empty))
    (else                            ;; zero elements
     (then empty empty))))
```

Both implementations perform to specification.

```
(split '())
;; => '(() ())

(split '(1)) 
;; => '((1) ())

(split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; => '((1 3 5 7) (2 4 6))
```

Grouping the result in a `list` is an intuitive default, but it's probable that you plan to do something with the separate parts anyway

```
(define my-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))

(let* ((result (split my-list))  ;; split the list into parts
       (l (car result))          ;; get the "left" part
       (r (cadr result)))        ;; get the "right" part
  (printf "odds: ~a, evens: ~a~n" l r))
;; odds: (1 3 5 7), evens: (2 4 6)
```

Above, continuation passing style gives us unique control over the returned result. The continuation is configurable at the call site, using a second parameter.

```
(split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) list)  ;; same as default
;; '((1 3 5 7) (2 4 6))

(split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) cons)
;; '((1 3 5 7) 2 4 6)

(split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
       (λ (l r)
         (printf "odds: ~a, evens: ~a~n" l r)))
;; odds: (1 3 5 7), evens: (2 4 6)

(split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
       (curry printf "odds: ~a, evens: ~a~n"))
;; odds: (1 3 5 7), evens: (2 4 6)
```

---

Oscar's answer using an auxiliary helper function or the first implementation in this post using `loop` are practical and idiomatic programs. Continuation passing style is a nice academic exercise, but I only demonstrated it here because it shows how to step around two complex tasks:

1. building up an output list without having to reverse it
2. returning multiple values

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to the definitions of `make-pair` and `make-tuple` that you're using. I can think of a recursive algorithm in terms of Scheme lists, it should be easy to adapt this to your requirements, just use `make-tuple` in place of `list`, `make-pair` in place of `cons` and make the necessary adjustments:

```
(define (split lst l1 l2)
  (cond ((empty? lst) ; end of list with even number of elements
         (list (reverse l1) (reverse l2))) ; return solution
        ((empty? (rest lst)) ; end of list with odd number of elements
         (list (reverse (cons (first lst) l1)) (reverse l2))) ; return solution
        (else ; advance two elements at a time, build two separate lists
         (split (rest (rest lst)) (cons (first lst) l1) (cons (second lst) l2)))))

(define (split-list lst)
  ; call helper procedure with initial values
  (split lst '() '()))
```

For example:

```
(split-list '(1 2))
=> '((1) (2))
(split-list '(1 2 3 4))
=> '((1 3) (2 4))
(split-list '(1 2 3))
=> '((1 3) (2))
(split-list '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '((1 3 5) (2 4))
(split-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
=> '((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` is kind of a `de-interleave` function. In many other languages, `split` names functions which create sublists/subsequences of a list/sequence which preserve the actual order. That is why I don't like to name this function `split`, because it changes the order of elements in some way.

**Tail-call-rescursive solution**

```
(define de-interleave (l (acc '(() ())))
  (cond ((null? l) (map reverse acc)) ; reverse each inner list
        ((= (length l) 1)             
         (de-interleave '() (list (cons (first l) (first acc))
                                  (second acc))))
        (else                         
         (de-interleave (cddr l) (list (cons (first l) (first acc)) 
                                       (cons (second l) (second acc)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the module deinprogramm/DMdA-vanilla.
The simplest way is to match the current state of the list and call it again with the rest:

```
(define split-list
 (lambda (x)
  (match x
   ;the result should always be a tuple
   (empty (make-tuple empty empty))
   ((list a) (make-tuple (list a) empty)) 
   ((list a b) (make-tuple (list a) (list b)))
   ;call split-list with the remaining elements, then insert the first two elements to each list in the tuple
   ((make-pair a (make-pair b c))
    ((lambda (t) 
     (make-tuple (make-pair a (first-tuple t))
                 (make-pair b (rest-tuple t))))
     (split-list c))))))
```